# How to locate a procedure in the body of a trigger

Tags: oracle, query, trigger, oracle-12c

I'd like to perform a validation by capturing all my triggers that call procedures.To do the search, I'm looking for the words "Call" and "Execute" in the trigger body

```sql
-- I'm using the following query:
SELECT
   OWNER,
   TRIGGER_NAME
FROM
   DBA_TRIGGERS
WHERE
   DBMS_LOB.INSTR(TRIGGER_BODY, 'CALL') > 0
      OR DBMS_LOB.INSTR(TRIGGER_BODY, 'EXECUTE') > 0;
```

But I'm getting an error:
ORA-00997: invalid use of data type LONG

How can I make this query?

Answer (score 4):

There's no need to search the text. You can leverage Oracle's dependency registration instead:

```
SELECT *
  FROM dba_dependencies
 WHERE type = 'TRIGGER'
   AND referenced_name NOT IN ('DBMS_STANDARD','STANDARD')
   AND referenced_type IN ('PROCEDURE','FUNCTION','PACKAGE')
```

If you *did* want to search the `trigger_body` content, because it's a `long` which has so many restrictions its nearly unusable, you'd need to either write it to a new table as a CLOB or use `dbms_sql.column_value_long` to progressively build a temporary CLOB. But that's rather complex and requires pages of code, something only advanced programmers would attempt. Further, `EXEC` is SQL*Plus syntax and `CALL` is a SQL statement. Neither are used within the PL/SQL language that triggers use. Procedures are invoked simply by naming them. Trying to parse text and look for procedure calls is like rewriting Oracle's PL/SQL parsing engine. They've already done that work for you at compile time and exposed the dependency chain through the `dba_dependencies` view.

Comment: Good morning, Paul.

Thanks for the explanations, using the query you provided I got the result I expected for my purposes.

Thank you for your attention.